# Having problems connecting to Local Host

Tags: apache, localhost, web-testing

I have downloaded and installed Apache for Windows 7 and am trying to set up my Local Host so that I can test an Eclipse web project. I currently cannot even connect to Local Host through my browser. When I enter `http://localhost/` into Chrome/Firefox I get a connection error. In Chrome:

```
This webpage is not available
Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This seems like some fairly basic configuration problem, but I don't have the experience to know what to try next. Would you mind giving me some things to try out?

If it helps I tried pinging `127.0.0.1` and I received a response, and the internet is still working as normal.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you type in a URL or IP Address in your browser eg. 127.0.0.1, you're browser assumes you're looking for port 80, usually written as 127.0.0.1:80.

It's possible Apache isn't running, or something else is already listening on port 80. On Windows, you  can see what's listening on which ports by running

```
netstat -a | find "LISTENING"
```

If something else is listening on port 80, Apache won't start up, and you must end the other process before starting Apache. After starting Apache, run netstat to be sure that Apache is listening on port 80.

If Apache is running and listening on 80, then it's likely you have some wrong configurations in your Apache setup.